# Pegar a url do boleto de pagamento do PagSeguro

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um problema pra pegar o boleto do pagseguro e abrir em uma nova aba do navegador. Quando envio os dados e escolho boleto a transação é executada normalmente porém não estou sabendo pegar o retorno pra exibir o boleto pro cliente. 
No Javascript fiz assim:

```
}else if(form_pg === 'BOLETO'){               
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'routers/boleto.php',
                data:{sHash:sHash,
                    name:name,
                    email:email,
                    ddd:ddd,
                    telephone:telephone,
                    form_pg:form_pg,
                    cep:cep,
                    street:street,
                    numberHouse:numberHouse,
                    complement:complement,
                    neighbordhood:neighborhood,
                    city:city,
                    state:state,
                    cpf:cpfBoletoBalance,                                                            
                    valor:valor
                },
                 dataType:'json',
                 success:function(response){  
                    if(response.error == true){
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro: ' + response.msg);
                    }else{
                        alert('Pagamento efetuado com sucesso, um email foi enviado pra você com os dados do boleto. Obrigado pela compra.');                          
                    }
                }
            });
```

No PHP que recebe o Ajax:

```php
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

PagSeguro\Library::initialize();    
PagSeguro\Library::cmsVersion()->setName("XXXXXXXXXXX")->setRelease("1.0.0");
PagSeguro\Library::moduleVersion()->setName("XXXXXXXXX")->setRelease("1.0.0");
PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::setEnvironment("production");
PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::setAccountCredentials("email.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::setCharset("UTF-8");
PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::setLog(true, "pagseguro.log");

$sHash = addslashes($_POST["sHash"]);
$nome = addslashes($_POST["name"]);
$email = addslashes($_POST["email"]);
$ddd = addslashes($_POST["ddd"]);
$telefone = str_replace('-', '', $_POST["telephone"]);
$forma_pagamento = addslashes($_POST["form_pg"]);
$cep = str_replace('-', '', $_POST["cep"]);
$rua = addslashes($_POST["street"]);
$numero = addslashes($_POST["numberHouse"]);
$complemento = addslashes($_POST["complement"]);
$bairro = addslashes($_POST["neighbordhood"]);
$cidade = addslashes($_POST["city"]);
$estado = addslashes($_POST["state"]);
$cpf_msk = str_replace('.', '', $_POST["cpf"]);
$cpf = str_replace('-', '', $cpf_msk);
$valor = addslashes($_POST["valor"]);


$boleto = new \PagSeguro\Domains\Requests\DirectPayment\Boleto();
$boleto->setReceiverEmail('barbosaflavioalves@hotmail.com');
$boleto->setReference($_SESSION['user_dm']); 
$boleto->setCurrency('BRL');



$boleto->addItems()->withParameters(
    $_SESSION['user_dm'],//identificador do produto
    "Conta Premium", //Nome do produto
    intval(1), // Quantidade
    floatval($valor)
);

//Comprador
$boleto->setSender()->setName($nome);
$boleto->setSender()->setEmail($email);
$boleto->setSender()->setDocument()->withParameters('CPF', $cpf);
$boleto->setSender()->setPhone()->withParameters(
    $ddd,
    $telefone
);

//Send Hash e IP
$boleto->setSender()->setHash($sHash);
$boleto->setSender()->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$boleto->setShipping()->setAddressRequired()->withParameters('FALSE');

$boleto->setMode('DEFAULT');

//Registrar o pagamento e recebe a resposta do pagseguro
    try{
        $resposta = $boleto->register(\PagSeguro\Configuration\Configure::getAccountCredentials());              
        echo $boleto->getLink() //Já tentei de tudo pra pegar o link;      
         exit();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => $ex->getMessage()));
        exit();
    }
```

Quando faço o pagamento por boleto e vou no arquivo de log do pagseguro o link do boleto está lá. Obrigado

Comment: O que vem na resposta do pagseguro? Dê uma olhada no conteúdo de `$resposta`

Comment: $responsta->paymentLink

Comment: JrD obrigado por responder, já dei um var_dump em $resposta e não tem nada um array vazio.

Comment: Wees obrigado por responder, já tentei dessa forma, inclusive é o que vem no xml de resposta do pagseguro mas da um erro informando que paymentLink não é reconhecido.  O pagseguro tem a pidor documentação que já vi. Estou precisando fazer funcionar urgênte

Comment: Problema resolvido, tanto a url do boleto como o notification estavam sendo capturados pelo arquivo de log que estava ativado, por isso o retorno era vazio. Pra resolver só desative o log.